# Run any Linux terminal command from TypeScript?

Tags: linux, bash, typescript, terminal

Is there a way to execute a Linux terminal command directly from within a TypeScript class? The idea is to do something similar to:

```
let myTerminal = new LinuxTerminal();
let terminalResult = myTerminal.run("sudo apt-get update");
```

**EDIT**:

I run this through Node JS with Angular.

Comment: Are you running in a Node JS environment? It's impossible to do this from a browser. How is this related to typescript? Did it work for you before in plain javascript?

Comment: @OmriLuzon Yes, I run this through Node JS and Angular. I'm merely trying to figure out if this is possible at all. Added this piece of info as *EDIT*.

Comment: So it should be rather *Run any Linux terminal command from node.js?*

Comment: @Kristianmitk That would solve the problem. Know any solution to that?

Comment: @Socrates did my answer that solve your problem? else supply us with more informations

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In **node.js** you could spawn a [child-process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html)

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');

exec('sudo apt-get update', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  // your callback
});
```

Comment: If I run my application through Electron it works, but if I run it through a browser like Chrome it blocks `exec(...)`. I believe this must be due to security reasons within Chrome, right?

Comment: Yes javascript code you run in the browser has no ability to communicate with the underlying system (which is a reasonable restriction). You will always need a backend (server) as an intermediary